# What does <special> do in a mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

While reading the code of some plugins, I found the key `<special>` being used.

Typing `:h <special>`, `:h <Special>` or `:h <SPECIAL>` yields nothing. I tried to search for it (`/\c<special>`) in `:h map`, but found nothing. Neither did I find any reference of it online.

What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is at `:help :map-<special>` (or `:help :map-special`, which is easier to type):

```
                        *:map-<special>* *:map-special*
Define a mapping with <> notation for special keys, even though the "<" flag
may appear in 'cpoptions'.  This is useful if the side effect of setting
'cpoptions' is not desired.  Example: >
    :map <special> <F12> /Header<CR>
<
```

Some values for `cpoptions` will not allow `<>` notation for keys, meaning they have to be entered literally (like the old vi days); *e.g.*, you would put

```
map - /Header^M
```

where the `^M` is actually a single byte inserted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A mapping with `<special>` fixes this even when `cpoptions` wouldn't allow it.

Comment: PS typing `:help special` followed by `<C-d>` shows some options, which is one way to find this topic; also, `:helpgrep <special>` gets you there almost immediately.